# How to join more than 3 tables in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can join 3 tables at Laravel laravel eloquent like this:

```
     B                 D                 E
+-----------+     +-----------+     +-----------+
| *id       |     | *id       |     | *id       |
|           |     |  B_id     |     |           |
|           |    /|  E_id     |\    |           |
|           |-----|           |-----|           |
|           |    \|           |/    |           |
|           |     |           |     |           |
+-----------+     +-----------+     +-----------+

$queries = DB::table('D')
    ->join('B', 'B.id', '=', 'D.B_id')
    ->join('E', 'E.id', '=', 'D.E_id')
    ->select('*')
    ->get();
```

So how can I join more than 3 tables like below:

```
     A                  B                 D                 E
+-----------+      +-----------+     +-----------+     +-----------+
| *id       |      | *id       |     | *id       |     | *id       |
| B_id      |      |           |     |  B_id     |     |           |
|           |\     |           |    /|  E_id     |\    |           |
|           +------|           |-----|           |-----|           |
|           |/     |           |    \|           |/    |           |
|           |      |           |     |           |     |           |
+-----------+      +-----------+     +-----------+     +-----------+
```

What I try to do in SQL is below:

```
SELECT * FROM A,B,C,D
WHERE B.id=A.B_id
AND B.id=D.B_id
AND D.E_id=E.id
```

Comment: you can create `DATABASE_VIEW`, read about it and use the `sqlyog` APP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad practice to use cross joins and then use join conditions in the `where` part of the query.

You need to convert your second query to use `INNER JOIN` (or simply `JOIN` which is the same).

Then the conversion to eloquent will be a lot more straight-forward. In your case you can write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM B 
    JOIN A ON B.id=A.B_id
    JOIN D ON B.id=D.B_id
    JOIN E ON E.id=D.E_id
```

Then your eloquent query will be straight forward as:

```php
$queries = DB::table('B')
    ->join('A', 'B.id', '=', 'A.B_id')
    ->join('D', 'B.id', '=', 'D.B_id')
    ->join('E', 'E.id', '=', 'D.E_id')
    ->select('*')
    ->get();
```